# ITfLanguageProfileNotifySink::OnLanguageChange only reporting when the window is active

Tags: c++, winapi

I would like to know when the system language has changed in my application, even when the application is not active. So I created an implementation using `ITfLanguageProfileNotifySink`. But, ITfLanguageProfileNotifySink::OnLanguageChange seems to only be executing when the window is active. How can I have this execute when the window is not the top active window?

Sample Code

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <msctf.h>

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);

class NotifyMe : protected ITfLanguageProfileNotifySink {
public:
    ITfSource *m_tfSource;
    DWORD m_dwCookie;

    void Init();

    virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE OnLanguageChange(LANGID langid, __RPC__out BOOL *pfAccept);
    virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE OnLanguageChanged();

    // IUnknown implementation
    virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE QueryInterface(REFIID riid, __RPC__deref_out void __RPC_FAR *__RPC_FAR *ppvObject);
    virtual ULONG STDMETHODCALLTYPE AddRef();
    virtual ULONG STDMETHODCALLTYPE Release();
    ULONG m_ulRefCount;     ///< COM object reference count
};

int WINAPI wWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, PWSTR pCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    // Register the window class.
    const wchar_t CLASS_NAME[] = L"Sample Window Class";

    WNDCLASS wc = {};

    wc.lpfnWndProc = WindowProc;
    wc.hInstance = hInstance;
    wc.lpszClassName = CLASS_NAME;

    RegisterClass(&wc);

    // Create the window.

    HWND hwnd = CreateWindowEx(
        0,                              // Optional window styles.
        CLASS_NAME,                     // Window class
        L"Learn to Program Windows",    // Window text
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,            // Window style

                                        // Size and position
        CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,

        NULL,       // Parent window    
        NULL,       // Menu
        hInstance,  // Instance handle
        NULL        // Additional application data
    );

    if(hwnd == NULL)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    CoInitialize(nullptr);

    NotifyMe notify;
    notify.Init();

    ShowWindow(hwnd, nCmdShow);


    MSG msg = {};
    while(GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0) > 0)
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    return 0;
}


void NotifyMe::Init() {
    m_tfSource = NULL;

    ITfInputProcessorProfiles *pProfiles;
    HRESULT hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_TF_InputProcessorProfiles, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_ITfInputProcessorProfiles, (LPVOID*)&pProfiles);
    if(SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
        hr = pProfiles->QueryInterface(IID_ITfSource, (LPVOID*)&m_tfSource);
        if(SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
            hr = m_tfSource->AdviseSink(IID_ITfLanguageProfileNotifySink, (ITfLanguageProfileNotifySink*)this, &m_dwCookie);
            if(FAILED(hr) || m_dwCookie == -1) {
                m_tfSource->Release();
                m_tfSource = NULL;
            }
        }

        pProfiles->Release();
    }
}


HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE NotifyMe::OnLanguageChange(LANGID langid, __RPC__out BOOL *pfAccept)
{
    if(pfAccept) *pfAccept = TRUE;
    return S_OK;
}


HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE NotifyMe::OnLanguageChanged()
{
    OutputDebugStringA("Language Changed");

    return S_OK;
}


HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE NotifyMe::QueryInterface(REFIID riid, __RPC__deref_out void __RPC_FAR *__RPC_FAR *ppvObject)
{
    if(!ppvObject)
        return E_INVALIDARG;

    if(riid == IID_IUnknown)
        *ppvObject = static_cast<IUnknown*>(this);
    else if(riid == IID_ITfLanguageProfileNotifySink)
        *ppvObject = static_cast<ITfLanguageProfileNotifySink*>(this);
    else {
        *ppvObject = NULL;
        return E_NOINTERFACE;
    }

    AddRef();
    return NOERROR;
}


ULONG STDMETHODCALLTYPE NotifyMe::AddRef()
{
    InterlockedIncrement(&m_ulRefCount);
    return m_ulRefCount;
}


ULONG STDMETHODCALLTYPE NotifyMe::Release()
{
    // Decrement the object's internal counter.
    ULONG ulRefCount = InterlockedDecrement(&m_ulRefCount);
    if(m_ulRefCount == 0)
        delete this;
    return ulRefCount;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch(uMsg)
    {
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return 0;

    case WM_PAINT:
    {
        PAINTSTRUCT ps;
        HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);

        FillRect(hdc, &ps.rcPaint, (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW + 1));

        EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
        return 0;
    }

    // i want to listen to these events when the window is not in focus
    case WM_SETFONT:
        OutputDebugStringA("Font Changed");
        break;
    case WM_INPUTLANGCHANGE:
        OutputDebugStringA("Language Changed - WndProc");
        break;

        // -- along with paint
        //case WM_PAINT:

    }
    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Comment: The [ITfLanguageProfileNotifySink](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/msctf/nn-msctf-itflanguageprofilenotifysink) interface is implemented by an **application**, application level.

Comment: @YangXiaoPo-MSFT Isn't that how I have done it here?

Comment: Yes. So, there is no problem about the interface. I have been finding a way detecting the language profile changed event independence of the active window.

Answer (score 1):

That's not how the `ITfLanguageProfileNotifySink` work. It is only for YOUR application.

What you need to understand is that every application got its own language just like yours. So when you switch to an app, the language there could be English, and when you switch back to any other app, it could be French, Japanese, Russian, or whatever language you set there.

What you want to achieve is to detect that change for "every" application, right? Then `ITfLanguageProfileNotifySink` is **not the way**.

You have to use **`GetKeyboardLayout`** instead because it allows you to get the language of **any** thread. But looks like you only want to detect the "active" thread, right? So you'd also want to pair it with `GetWindowThreadProcessId(GetForegroundWindow(), NULL)` because this would get the thread of the currently active window for you.

And for that to be integrated correctly with your application, you also have to modify your loop so that it doesn't "wait" for UI messages and block your detection scheme by using `PeekMessage()`.

```
MSG msg = {};
    const int period_ms = 10;
    while (true)
    {
        if (PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))
        {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }
        static LANGID currentLangId = LOWORD(::GetKeyboardLayout(0));
        // Get active window thred
        DWORD threadId = ::GetWindowThreadProcessId(::GetForegroundWindow(), NULL);
        LANGID newLangId = LOWORD(::GetKeyboardLayout(threadId));
        if (newLangId != currentLangId)
        {
            currentLangId = newLangId;
            wchar_t szLangName[256];
            GetLocaleInfo(MAKELCID(newLangId, SORT_DEFAULT), LOCALE_SENGLANGUAGE, szLangName, 256);
            OutputDebugString(szLangName);
            OutputDebugString(L"\n");
        }
        Sleep(period_ms);
    }
```

Note that if the language changed in an app from `X` -> `Y`, it'll print `'Y'`, then when you switch to another app, it'll mostly print `'X'` first and then in the next iteration, it'd print `'Y'` right after. That's because "most" apps change their language accordingly to the previous window **after** you open them.

And some other applications would keep their language changes only inside the application no matter what how you change it outside of it. It is different from one app to another. But with that loop, you'll be able to detect all changes.

Comment: Thank you. I am curious, why does `Sleep` need to be used?

Comment: @chadb Because unlike your code which had `GetMessage(...)` that blocks the execution of your program, this code is the one that fetches and so it is non-blocking which means there's nothing that'd stop your program from wasting an entire CPU core. Imagine iterating every less than 1 nanosecond on this code; it is impossible for a human to change the language back and forth in less than 10ms; let alone aboserve the change.

`GetMessage` is actually sleep'ing too. Its only problem is that it works only inside your window. So we had to re-implement its function but without that limitation.